# Geofence Android isn't working (IntentService isn't called)

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-geofence

Here are my code :

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pounya.id.location3">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service android:name=".GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Activity_main.xml (Layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pounya.id.location3.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_geofences_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addGeofencesButtonHandler"
        android:text="@string/add_geofences" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package pounya.id.location3;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

    protected static final String TAG = "Main Activity";

    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate is called");

        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);

        // Empty list for storing geofences.
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        //Set up the GeoFencing client
        mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
        populateGeofenceList();

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"Permision is granted");
                    addGeofencesButtonHandler(null);
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.

                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if ( (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) ) {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{/*.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,*/ Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);
            }
            return;
        }

        try {
            Log.v(TAG,"try addGeofences is called");
            mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            // Geofences added
                            // ...
                            Log.v(TAG,"Geofence is added");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            // Failed to add geofences
                            // ...
                            Log.v(TAG,"Geofence is not added");
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }

    }

    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        Log.v(TAG,"populateGeoFenceList is called");
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constant.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {

            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                    // geofence.
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                    // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constant.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )

                    // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                    // removed after this period of time.
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constant.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)

                    // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                    // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                    // Create the geofence.
                    .build());
        }
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        Log.v(TAG,"getGeofencing Request is called");
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();

        //The INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER flag indicates that geofencing service should trigger a
        //GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER notification when the geofence is added and if the device
        //is already inside that geofence
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);

        //Add the geofence to be monitored by geofencing service
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);

        //Return a GeofencingRequest
        return builder.build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Log.v(TAG,"getGeofencePendingIntent is called");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.v(TAG,"GoogleAPI is connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onResult is called");
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
            // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
            String errorMessage = GeoFenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    status.getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

**GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService.java**

```
package pounya.id.location3;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
    protected static final String TAG = "geofence-transitions-service";

    public GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
        Log.v(TAG,"GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService's constructor is called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.v(TAG,"GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService's onCreate is called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onHandleIntent is called");
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeoFenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );
            Toast.makeText(this,"NOTIFICATION",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            Context context,
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        Log.v(TAG,"getGeofenceTransitionDetails is called");

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        Log.v(TAG,"getTransitionString is called");
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        Log.v(TAG,"sendNotification is called");
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default");

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

**Constant.java**

```
package pounya.id.location3;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import java.util.HashMap;

public final class Constant {
    protected static final String TAG = "Constant Class";

    private Constant() {
    }

    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "pounya.id.location3";

    public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = PACKAGE_NAME + ".SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME";

    public static final String GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY";

    /**
     * Used to set an expiration time for a geofence. After this amount of time Location Services
     * stops tracking the geofence.
     */
    public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS = 12;

    /**
     * For this sample, geofences expire after twelve hours.
     */
    public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    //public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1609; // 1 mile, 1.6 km
    public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 20; // 1 mile, 1.6 km

    /**
     * Map for storing information about airports in the San Francisco bay area.
     */
    public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        // San Francisco International Airport.
        BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("KOST", new LatLng(-6.879573, 107.614239));

        // Googleplex.
        BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("JALAN", new LatLng(-6.879820, 107.614321));

        // Test
        BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("MASJID", new LatLng(-6.879878, 107.613335));
    }
}
```

**GeoFenceErrorMessages.java**

```
package pounya.id.location3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;


public class GeoFenceErrorMessages {

    protected static String TAG = "GeoFenceErrorMessages";

    /**
     * Prevents instantiation.
     */
    private GeoFenceErrorMessages() {}

    /**
     * Returns the error string for a geofencing error code.
     */
    public static String getErrorString(Context context, int errorCode) {
        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate is called");
        Resources mResources = context.getResources();
        switch (errorCode) {
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_not_available);
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_too_many_geofences);
            case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.geofence_too_many_pending_intents);
            default:
                return mResources.getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_error);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the App and click the Button, the Logcat give me these messages:

```
03-31 10:32:29.254 2591-2591/pounya.id.location3 V/Main Activity: Permision is granted
03-31 10:32:29.257 2591-2591/pounya.id.location3 V/Main Activity: try addGeofences is called
03-31 10:32:29.257 2591-2591/pounya.id.location3 V/Main Activity: getGeofencing Request is called
03-31 10:32:29.258 2591-2591/pounya.id.location3 V/Main Activity: getGeofencePendingIntent is called
03-31 10:32:29.348 2591-2591/pounya.id.location3 V/Main Activity: Geofence is added
```

The Coordinate that is being used in the Constant.java is the Coordinate of my home. I have tried to go out from my home (more than 1km) and then returned to my home, I didn't get any notification or Toast.

I don't have any idea what is the root problem. I have used Running Permission and insert GeoFenceTransitionsIntentService in AndroidManifest.xml

Could anybody help me to figure it out? Thank you for the help. I have spent a lot of hours to fix this, but I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. Since Android 8 background work is more limited. There is a new way of calling `IntentService`. Check out newest Android guidelines for implementing Geofence listener:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing

In short, you just need to use `GeofencingClient` for calling `PendingIntent` which contains `IntentService`.

```
private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}
```

Use link provided above for full example.

Comment: Isn't he doing the same thing in the code he provided ?